# Подскажите, пжста, хорошие ресурсы, где можно найти полезные задачки по Golang для начинающих (с решениями и подсказками)

Tags: golang

Недавно начал изучать теорию Go. Пока прошел массивы, срезы, структуры, методы и интерфейсы.
Хочу потренироваться, чтобы получить опыт и закрепить полученные знания, но не знаю, где можно найти  хорошие задачки (желательно, чтобы можно было проверить себя и увидеть решения при затруднениях).
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/